# Are there performance improvements to Google services APIs if your server is hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

We are currently hosted on Amazon's AWS platform, however our server makes extensive use of many of the Google services API's including:

- Google Maps
- Google Static Maps
- Google Places

During normal usage, some of these API requests can take over 1-3 seconds and that's not exactly great for user experience. I wonder if there are any performance gains if we were to host our server on top of Google App Engine instead. An example would be getting better performance if you make use of as many AWS platforms for your system rather than spreading them out between multiple cloud services provider.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the roundtrip to call the api will be faster but not the actual api. It can make a noticeable difference if you are calling many google apis on the same servlet call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to have a link to anything from Google that happens to mention this performance advantage?